# How to connect to AWS AppSync using Cognito Identity Pools and Amplify

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I have an AWS AppSync API that uses IAM roles for authentication. I'm using the Amplify GraphQL client to connect to the AppSync server. The image below describes the steps that need to take place to get the IAM credentials, which I'm assuming Amplify is capable of performing. However, I can't find any documentation on how to set up a working example.

Note that I'm using a Cognito user pool directly for authentication, not an external provider like Google or Facebook.

[image: Access AWS Services with a User Pool and an Identity Pool]

So far I'm able to authenticate the user and get a JWT Token (step 1):

```
const Amplify = require('aws-amplify').default
const { Auth } = require('aws-amplify')


Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    userPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USERPOOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.COGNITO_WEBCLIENT_ID,
  },
})

Auth.signin(username, password)
  .then((user) => {
    const token = user.idToken.jwtToken
    // I've got the token - what next?
  })
```

How can I request the IAM credentials from the identity pool (step 2), and use them to access the AppSync API (step 3) using Amplify?

If Amplify isn't able to get the credentials itself, I can use `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` to request them using the AWS SDK, however, I can't see a way of passing them to Amplify to authenticate the API requests (refer to [this issue I created](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3116) for more details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your amplify config has an AppSync API with AWS_IAM authentication and a cognito user pool, Amplify will use the id token to get AWS credential automatically.

To actually call the AppSync API, all you have to do is:

```
API.graphql({query})
```

Comment: This is correct, and it does indeed work automatically. I was missing the `Auth.identityPoolId` property from my Amplify config object, however. This is required in addition to the `region`, `userPoolId` and `userPoolWebClientId` properties shown in my question.

Comment: How do you know what objects (and what structure) is accepted by Amplify.configure?

Comment: @LukasRossa See here for client configuration (`Amplify.configure()`): https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/client-configuration/configuring-amplify-categories/q/platform/js/#top-level-configuration-6

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use cognito to authenticate my client and then passed the jwtToken to the aws-appsync client to be able to use APPSYNC with AMAZON_COGINITO_USER_POOLS.  Also in the code you will see where I used API_KEY as an alternative.  I left the API_KEY commented out.  I share this as an alternative for those that also want to try to access with Apollo client and aws-appsync.

```
if (!process.browser) {
  global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
}

const appSyncClientOptions = {
  url: awsConfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint, 
  region: awsConfig.aws_appsync_region,
  auth: {
    // type: 'API_KEY',
    // apiKey: awsConfig.aws_appsync_apiKey,
    type: awsConfig.aws_appsync_authenticationType,   // 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS'
    jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getAccessToken().getJwtToken()
  },
  disableOffline: true,
};

const apolloClientOptions = {
  link: createAppSyncLink({
    ...appSyncClientOptions,
    resultsFetcherLink: createHttpLink({ uri: appSyncClientOptions.url, fetch })
  })  
};

const client = new Client(appSyncClientOptions, apolloClientOptions);

const WithProvider = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Rehydrated>
      <GqlList />
    </Rehydrated>
  </ApolloProvider>
)

export default WithProvider;
```

Comment: Note this answer is using `AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS` with aws-appsync, not `AWS_IAM` with Amplify, as explicitly mentioned in my question. This could be very confusing for people looking for an answer to that question.

Comment: I think the original question is bit unclear.  Author states "Note that I'm using a Cognito user pool directly for authentication..."  But your point is well taken to understand there is a difference between AWS_IAM and AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS

Comment: Identity pool is NOT user pool